# How to GZIP a XSLT webpage

Tags: xml, xslt, gzip

I am working on a webpage and I use XSLT as template engine.

I only send XML and the XSLT file to the requester and let the receiver's browser render it in HTML.

I would like to know how I could GZip the XSL Stylesheet and maybe the XML I'm sending to the requester.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ob_gzhandler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php)

Comment: I added @ob_start("ob_gzhandler") atop my XML and XSLT file and it seems to work according to Firebug. Even better, I found a way to add it to htaccess file and it still works but apparently it wont apply gzip to JS and CSS files. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache, you should to take a look into [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look into HTTP Compression.  This is something you set on your webserver that causes all traffic to be compressed, IF a client's browser supports it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you using?  This will probably be more of a setting on your webserver than  coding on your part.

Comment: I use Apache on my local server